# Select and/or replace specific array inside pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Here is my reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [np.zeros(2), np.array([1,2])], 'y' : [np.array([3,2]),0], 'z' : [np.array([4,5]),np.zeros(2)], 't' : [np.array([3,4]),np.array([4,5])]})
```

My goal is to change `np.zeros(2)` to `np.Nan` so as to be able to compute the mean two-dimensional array for each row excluding 0.

I have tried:

`df.replace(np.zeros(2),np.NaN)`

`df[df.eq(np.zeros(2)).any(axis=1)]`

`df.where(df == [np.zeros(2)])`

`df[df == np.zeros(2)]`

all of which are expected to worked had the item I am looking not been an array.

Obviously, being new at Python, there must be a concept that I am not grasping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't vectorize with objects as values.

Use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) and [`numpy.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html):

```
df[df.applymap(lambda x: np.array_equal(x, np.zeros(2)))] = np.nan
```

Updated `df`:

```
        x       y       z       t
0     NaN  [3, 2]  [4, 5]  [3, 4]
1  [1, 2]       0     NaN  [4, 5]
```

Alternative with [`allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html):

```
df[df.applymap(lambda x: np.allclose(x, 0))] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
        x       y       z       t
0     NaN  [3, 2]  [4, 5]  [3, 4]
1  [1, 2]     NaN     NaN  [4, 5]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, any idea why I can't change that pesky 0 by np.NaN even though it is recognized as being equal to 0 the integer?

Comment: If you want to change all arrays/scalar that are equivalent to `0` use `allclose` in place of `array_equal`

Comment: My bad I didn't mean to ask you how to do it all in one go, I was just wondering how to deal with that single 0 separately after your solution. For some reason I couldn't replace it by np.nan.

Comment: I see, then use as many masks as you want: `m1 = df.applymap(lambda x: np.array_equal(x, np.zeros(2))) ; m2 = df.eq(0) ; df[m1|m2] = np.nan`

Comment: Btw, your `df.replace(np.NaN, something)` is in the incorrect order. You should use `df.replace(something, np.NaN)`